# Factual API vs Google Places API in terms of Distance Matrix (distance and time)

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, factual

I need enough accuracy in my app but Google Places seems to be poorly accurate filtering by category. So I'm considering migrating to Factual API. Do you guys have used it? What do you think about its accuracy?

In the other hand, I NEED to know the distance to a place and the estimated travel time. I'm getting this info with Google Distance Matrix API, but I don't know if Factual has this functionality or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Factual's api for one app and the result is worse than Google Place's, at least for the super-market/grocery category

Answer (score 2):

If the Factual API allows you to display the data on a Google Map, you can use the Factual data with the Distance Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Factual provides distance in query results(in meters from search center).  It has a much better category tree system. Factual allows "IncludeAny(Category ids)"  (Google only has single level types and does not allow multiple types search). What I do is use Factual for initial search and Google Places for detail on a particular place.  Google places has photo[s], reviews(3)and  openNow(boolean).

The quality of data is slightly better in Google. (Both need work)